# Integral of $\sqrt{16x^{2}+9}$ with respect to x

Tags: calculus

Find the Integral of $\sqrt{16x^{2}+9}$ with respect to x

My try: $\int\sqrt{16x^{2}+9} dx =\int(16x^{2}+9)^{1/2}dx$ then make u substitution $u=16x^{2}+9$
but then have no idea how to continue

Comment: try to  interpret it as  $(4*x)^2+9$

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) will show you step-by-step calculations for solving any simple integral like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $u=4x$, yours will be 
$$\int \sqrt{16x^2+9}dx=\frac 14\int\sqrt{u^2+9}du.$$

Then, you can use the following :

$$\int\sqrt{u^2+A}du=\frac{1}{2}\left(u\sqrt{u^2+A}+A\ln|u+\sqrt{u^2+A}|\right)$$

Comment: I dont understand your way

Comment: @mathlove we together  found solution

Comment: @user120764: I added a bit. Does this help?

Comment: thanks a lot! but where did you get the last relation

Comment: http://integral-table.com/integral-table.html#SECTION00004000000000000000 look there,it is already existed formulas

Comment: @user120764: Well, it is a well known formula.

Comment: @mathlove +1 for you elegant solution

Comment: I want a proof for that formula

Comment: You'll know that this is true if you differenciate the right hand side.

Comment: ok thanks for all

Comment: @user120764 please  dont forget to  evaluate my answer too :)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$I=\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}dx=\int dx \sqrt{x^2+a^2}-\int\left(\int dx \frac{d \sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{dx}\right)dx$$

$$=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx$$

$$=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-\int \frac{x^2+a^2-a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx$$

$$=x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-I+a^2\int \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx$$

For $\displaystyle \int \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx,$ use  [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)

Now $\displaystyle 16x^2+9=16\left(x^2+\left(\frac34\right)^2\right)$

Answer (score 0):

if we interpret it as

$\int(\sqrt{(4*x)^2+9}dx$

now put $y=4*x$

from there you get $dy=4*dx$

or  $dx=dy/4$

or you have

$\int(\sqrt{y^2+9}dy/4$

now apply  as @mathlove said

table of integrals

http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf

try to  represent you integral as given in table